# Why is a pendulum an example of harmonic motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I've heard a lot of people say that a pendulum moving back and forth on a fixed-length spring is an example of harmonic motion. But when I derive the governing equation for a pendulum, I get

$$\theta'' = \frac{-g}{L} \sin(\theta)$$

(see for example video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_di4Zn4wz4) for a full derivation)

and I thought the equation of a harmonic oscillator was

$$x'' = -k x$$

like for springs. Why do people call a pendulum an example of harmonic motion if it doesn't satisfy the second equation?

(I think it's just because they use the small angle approximation $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ and call it a day.)

Comment: You answered yourself with the last sentence in parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you figured this one out.  Pendulum equations only apply for small perturbations, and even then it's only approximate.

Comment: Note that Hooke's law is only approximately true so even for a spring the equation is actually $\ddot x = -kx + O(x^2)$

Comment: I'll "connect the final dot".  sin($\theta$) = $\theta$.  Acceleration of the pendulum bob is proportional to $\theta$ because $a=g sin(\theta)$, so the force on the pendulum bob is also proportional to $\theta$.  For any object whose restoring force is linear and opposes the displacement from equilibrium, that object demonstrates simple harmonic motion

Comment: I originally overthought this and tried to show $\sin(\theta)'' = -k \sin(\theta)$ for some $k$. I was very unsuccessful.